# UTC to local timezone in SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a Login Audit report for citrix. Its a very simple script and all working fine but time I am getting is UTC so need to convert this to NZ Time 
Below is script can some please add whatever need to add to make it work 
Thanks in Advance

```
Select * From [CitrixXenAppMonitoring].[MonitorData].[user] as DUser
    Inner join [CitrixXenAppMonitoring].[MonitorData].[session] as DSession on DSession.UserId = DUser.ID
    left join [CitrixXenAppMonitoring].[MonitorData].[Machine] as DMachine on DSession.MachineID = DMachine.Id
    left join [CitrixXenAppMonitoring].[MonitorData].[Catalog] as DCatalogue on DCatalogue.Id = DMachine.CatalogId
    full outer join [CitrixXenAppMonitoring].[MonitorData].[Connection] as DConnection on DConnection.Id = DSession.CurrentConnectionId
    Where DUser.Username = 'JanineD'
    Order by DSession.StartDate
```

Comment: Do you mean one of the returned column is of DateTime type(mention exact data type) and its value need to be converted into NZ time?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at the link below and take a couple of minutes to improve your question. It is very hard to solve your problem when you haven't really given us the preconditions 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 you cannot convert timezone. You can create a CLR function to convert time.

check the link 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2339/converting-utc-to-local-time-with-sql-server-clr/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datatype is datetime and New Zeeland is GMT+12..Replace getdate() with your column in the query below.

```
 select DATEADD(hour,12,getdate())
```